# Slovak (and Czech) babel gives problems with cmidrule and cline

Tags: babel, booktabs

I tried to use the Slovak language with the `booktabs` package.

Let's see a couple of cases.

1. `slovak` is included in the options to `babel`

   ```
   \usepackage[english,slovak]{babel}
   ```

   or

   ```
   \usepackage[slovak,english]{babel}
   ```

   or

   ```
   \usepackage[slovak]{babel}`
   ```
2. "slovak" is NOT included in the options to `babel`

   ```
   \usepackage[english]{babel}
   ```

Similarly two cases for `\cmidrule`

A. `\cmidrule{2-3}` is included in the table

B. `\cmidrule{2-3}` is NOT included in the table

If both (`slovak`+`\cmidrule`) are included (case 1A), then following error occurrs

```
Paragraph ended before \@@@cmidrule was complete
```

(and a lot of other errors)

In the other cases (1B, 2A and 2B) (NO `slovak` or NO `\cmidrule`), then `pdflatex` is succesful

Does anybody know why 1A is wrong?

And how to use `slovak` and `\cmidrule` together (case 1A)?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[english,slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
A & B & C \\
%\cmidrule{2-3}
A & B & C \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I have Win7, TeXstudio 2.5.2

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I've taken the liberty of reformatting your question for greater clarity.

Comment: `slovak` makes the `-` an active character. This has to be reversed for `booktabs`. (The same is true for the standard `\cline`.)

Answer (score 26):

The `slovak` (and also `czech`) module for `babel` not only breaks `\cmidrule`, but also the kernel command `\cline` (and possibly many others).

Since the active `-` is used for hyphenation, its role shouldn't be important in tables. The following hack seems to fix things:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[english,slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\tabular{\shorthandoff{-}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
A & B & C \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
A & B & C \\
\cline{1-2}
A & B & C \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

A less invasive hack is to change the delimiter in the definition of `\@@@cmidrule` and of `\@cline`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[english,slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
% Change the `-` delimiter to an active character
\xpatchparametertext\@@@cmidrule{-}{\cA-}{}{}
\xpatchparametertext\@cline{-}{\cA-}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
A & B & C \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
A & B & C \\
\cline{1-2}
A & B & C \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

A package-free version (it could be made to work also without `\unexpanded`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\toks0=\expandafter{\@cline{#1}-{#2}\@nil}
\@ifpackageloaded{booktabs}{%
  \toks2=\expandafter{\@@@cmidrule[{#1}-{#2}]{#3}{#4}}%
}{}
\catcode`-=\active
\edef\x{\gdef\unexpanded{\@cline#1-#2\@nil}{\the\toks0}}\x
\@ifpackageloaded{booktabs}{%
  \edef\x{\gdef\unexpanded{\@@@cmidrule[#1-#2]#3#4}{\the\toks2}}\x
}{}
\endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
A & B & C \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
A & B & C \\
\cline{1-2}
A & B & C \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The patch is independent of the loading of `booktabs`, but of course it must be placed after it.

Answer (score 18):

The option `slovak` makes `-` an active character.

The macro `\@@@cmidrule` which is internally used by `\cmidrule` to split the argument `2-3` at the `-` is defined with an `-` of catcode `12` (the default).

The following code just re-defines `\@@@cmidrule` with an active `-`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[english,slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \catcode`\-=\active
    \AtBeginDocument{
    \def\@@@cmidrule[#1-#2]#3#4{\global\@cmidla#1\relax
        \global\advance\@cmidla\m@ne
        \ifnum\@cmidla>0\global\let\@gtempa\@cmidrulea\else
        \global\let\@gtempa\@cmidruleb\fi
        \global\@cmidlb#2\relax
        \global\advance\@cmidlb-\@cmidla
        \global\@thisrulewidth=#3
        \@setrulekerning{#4}
        \ifnum\@lastruleclass=\z@\vskip \aboverulesep\fi
        \ifnum0=`{\fi}\@gtempa
        \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\futurenonspacelet\@tempa\@xcmidrule}
    }
\endgroup
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
A & B & C \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
A & B & C \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved me a lot of time and energy.

Answer (score 3):

had the same problem.

As others have said, the problem arises from using czech(or slovak) babel.

On some [czech forum](http://www.abclinuxu.cz/tex/poradna/show/325037) i found this fix:

```
\begin{table}
  \catcode`\-=12
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

it changes the category of the `-` character back to where it should be.

this change can be either done globally or only in tables.

Comment: At last that was already mentioned by the other two answers .... Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2):

The `czech` ans `slovak` languages make hyphen active so it can be used as a macro allowing `\splithyphens` (i.e. repeating hyphen in a line-break) to work. If you do not need `\splithyphens` you can deactivate the hyphen by following:

```
\usepackage[english,slovak]{babel}
\AtBeginDocument{\shorthandoff{-}}
```

Later you can activate it again by using:

```
\shorthandon{-}
```