# Table error after using \cline

Tags: tables, arrays, multirow

I try to create bigger table in TeXworks where are different horizontal as well as vertical lines. Everything works fine but it always crash on the `\cline` command (when I use `\hline` it works perfectly).
Anyone know where should be problem?

I use packages:

```
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

Source of the table:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{11}{|l}}
\hline
& & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Longer text} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Longer text}\\
\cline{3-9}
& & a& b & c & d & ei & f & g \\
\hline
\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{text}}} & description & 2 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & -1\\
\cline{2-9}
& description & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
\cline{2-9}
& description & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & -2 & 2 & -2\\ 
\hline
\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{text}}} & description & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & -1 & 2 & 0\\
\\cline{2-9}
& description & -1 & 0 & 2 & 2 & -2 & 1 & -2\\
\cline{2-9}
& description & 1 & 2 & 2 &  & -1 & 1 & -1\\
\cline{2-9}
& description & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Multi-row table}
\label{tab:multirow}
\end{table}
```

Comment: This is the same problem as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111999/slovak-babel-vs-cmidrule

Comment: I modified the related question's title to reflect this.

Comment: Many thanks for the link. Before \begin{document} I've added \usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\tabular{\shorthandoff{-}} and it works!!!

Comment: I guess I have similair problem also with aligning too wide table. I have tried \makebox[\textwidth][c]{} but I got error message Argument of \@cline has an extra }. \par l.107 \hline} Do you have any idea what should be wrong?

Comment: The problem with the patch with `\preto` won't work if `tabular` is in the argument to another command. :( The more complex patch proposed in the answers is needed for coping with this further problem; either mine with `regexpatch` or the equivalent one by Qrrbrbirlbel.