# Using ranges with pdfpages fails

Tags: xetex, pdf, pdfpages, include

The [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf) says the following:

> E.g.: `pages=-` will insert all pages of the document [...]

however, when I put `\includepdf[pages=-]{foobar.pdf}` in my LaTeX doc (compiled w/ `xelatex`), I get this error:

```
! Package pdfpages Error: Cannot find file `-'.
```

Similarly, just using a range like `\includepdf[pages={1,3,5-last}]{foobar.pdf}` results in:

```
 <use  "foobar.pdf" >
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   -
l.91 ...df[pages={1,3,5-last}]{foobar.pdf}
```

I'm using the latest `pdfpages` downloaded from CTAN.

Any idea where could the problem lie?

edit:
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages={1,3-5}]{foobar.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: In my experiment, lines like `\includepdf[pages=-]{foobar.pdf}` and `\includepdf[pages={1,3-5}]{foobar.pdf}` succeed, but I get failure when I try `pages={1,3-last}`.

Comment: @egreg Same on my side. It looks like there is some issue with `ppxetex.def`

Comment: @egreg The error actually appears even when using "defined" ranges like 3-5 at my end.

Comment: @TomášM. Can you please add `\listfiles` to a minimal example such as touhami's and show the result you find in the terminal or in the log file after “File List”?

Comment: @TomášM. ***Now*** it's clear! The problem is of course `\usepackage[czech]{babel}`! But there's hope, don't worry.

Comment: @egreg The document would actually not compile otherwise, I assumed it was some overzealous l10n thing kicking in, what's the problem with `babel`?
edit: You are right, though! That's strange.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the same as in [Slovak (and Czech) babel gives problems with cmidrule and cline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111999/slovak-and-czech-babel-gives-problems-with-cmidrule-and-cline): the `czech` option to `babel` makes the `-` character into a shorthand and this disrupts the working of the `pages` option.

Quick fix:

```
\shorthandoff{-}\includepdf[pages=1,3-5]{foobar.pdf}\shorthandon{-}
```

Better fix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchparametertext{\AM@checkrange}{-}{\cA-}{}{}
\xpatchparametertext{\AM@checklast}{-}{\cA-}{}{}
\regexpatchcmd{\AM@readlisti}{-}{\cA-}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages={1,3-4}]{largefrac.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Note that, for some reasons, the `last` keyword doesn't work with XeLaTeX, but specifying `3-` instead of `3-last` is fine.

Comment: Today the command "\includepdf[pages={1,3-4}]{largefrac.pdf}" help  me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just copile this code and it work very good

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{31roegel.pdf}
\end{document}
```

for the second problem use

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={1,5-}]{31roegel.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try to use `pages={1,3-last}` and compile with xelatex

Comment: that does not work but pages={1,3-} do the job

Comment: This does not answer the question, anyway.

Comment: Why? help me to see the problem

Comment: @touhami The same code doesn't work on my end.

Comment: Ah for me it works very very good

Comment: As it turns out the input/fontencodings of czech language (with `babel`) is quite crucial for this question

Comment: Yes i see the edit in question

Comment: @karlkoeller please can you show to me the problem in my code it works well for me

Comment: There's no problem with your code, but it has nothing to do with the OP's question...