# How to create angular matrix with rectangle as borders

Tags: matrices, border

I would like to replicate a matrix like this:

[image: angular matrix]

A matrix with straight horizontal and vertical lines forming a rectangle around its content.

I tried using array environment with hlines

```
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccccccc|}
      & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
    \hline
    a & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    c & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    d & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    e & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \hline
\end{array}
$$
```

but got this intead:

[image: wrong matrix]

Is it possible to do it in latex or do i need an external program to generate such picture and insert it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can of course do this with LaTeX. To generate a horizontal line that spans a subset of the columns, use `\cline{x-y}`, where makes a rule from column x to column y.

To remove the vertical bars from the top row you need to override the column specification for two of the cells with `\multicolumn`. The syntax is `\multicolumn{<number of columns>}{<column specifier>}{<cell content>}`. The first and last column have `c|` as column specifier, using `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` in the first cell changes that to `c` without the vertical bar.

Finally, don't use `$$ .. $$` for display math in LaTeX, it is recommended to use `\[ \]` instead.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[czech,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\[
\shorthandoff{-}
\begin{array}{c|cccccccc|}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{}    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{8} \\
    \cline{2-9}
    a & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    c & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    d & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    e & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \cline{2-9}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Error: Paragraph ended before \@cline was complete.

Comment: @Youda008 My code does not produce that error, so you must have modified it somehow. I don't know what would cause that error to show, perhaps `\cline{2-9`,  i.e. without the closing brace.

Comment: Something is changing meaning of symbol '-'. Probably caused by \usepackage[czech,english]{babel}

Comment: Adding \catcode`\-=12 at the beginning of math environment is the solution.

Comment: Or `\shorthandoff{-}` in a useful place, see edited answer.

Comment: See [Slovak (and Czech) babel gives problems with cmidrule and cline](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111999/) for the problem of `\cline` and `babel-czech`

Comment: @egreg Thanks! Not surprised it has been asked about before.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a code. Don't use `$$ … $$` for displaymah, but `\[ … \]`.
I loaded the `array` package to have some more functionalities (less tight vertical spacing, and a simpler code for repetition of cells with the same specifier):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, array}

\begin{document}

\[ \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}\begin{array}{c|*{8}{c}|}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{3} & \mathbf{4} & \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{6} & \mathbf{7 }& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\mathbf{8}} \\
  \cline{2-9}
  \mathbf{a} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \mathbf{b} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \mathbf{c} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \mathbf{d} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \mathbf{e} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \cline{2-9}
  \end{array} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With `{NiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{NiceMatrix}
      & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & \\
    a & \Block[draw]{5-8}{}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    c & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    d & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    e & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{NiceMatrix}\]
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: It even works out of the box with `babel-czech`!

Answer (score 2):

What we can do in OpTeX:

```
\table{($)c($)|8c|}{
  \mspan1[c]{}  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & \mspan1[c]{8} \crlp{2-9}
              a & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
              b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
              c & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
              d & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
              e & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \crlp{2-9}
}

\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `\tikzmark`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw ([yshift=1.2\ht\strutbox,xshift=-3pt]{pic cs:start}) 
  rectangle ([xshift=3pt,yshift=-\dp\strutbox]{pic cs:end});
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{matrix}
& \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{3} & \mathbf{4}
& \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{6} & \mathbf{7} & \mathbf{8}\\
\mathbf{a} & 
  \tikzmark{start}
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\mathbf{b} &
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\mathbf{c} &
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\mathbf{d} &
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\mathbf{e} &
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\tikzmark{end}
\end{matrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Note that this requires two passes when the matrix changes, in order to be properly typeset.

[image]