# Compilation runs on forever when using \cline in a table

Tags: compiling, cline

Im using texstudio and have this problem that whenever i use the \cline command and try to compile, it starts compiling and never finishes here is what im trying to compile. Im using this source https://github.com/Kyslik/FEIStyle

```
\newpage
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
                                                                                        \hline
    Typ algoritmu                   & Kryptosystém      & Level bezpe\v cnosti (bit)    \\
                                    &                   & 80   & 128  & 192  & 256      \\
    Faktorizácia celých \v císel    & RSA               & 1024 & 3072 & 7680 & 15360    \\
    Diskrétny logaritmus            & DH, DSA, Elgamal  & 1024 & 3072 & 7680 & 15360    \\ \cline{1-2}
    Eliptické krivky                & ECDH, ECDSA       & 160  & 256  & 384  & 512      \\ 
    Symetrický                      & AES, 3DES         & 80   & 128  & 192  & 256      \\
                                                                                        \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please provide code of your table in form of complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. image of code is not usable.

Comment: added the picture and a link to the source i used

Comment: please, not a picture, copy code from your editor. image we can't compile ... it require that we should retype your code from scratch :-(

Comment: Never ever post a picture of your code, do you really think others want to type that code to test it? A link to the class is fine, but please update your question and paste the code to it such that it is copyable by others.

Comment: is this sufficient ?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! No, a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), should be compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: No, it is not. @Zarko told you very clearly what the code should look like. If I put your table in a simple document based on the `\documentclass{article}`, there is no error. (The table would benefit from `&`s in the first row, though.)

Comment: This seems like a case of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111999/slovak-and-czech-babel-gives-problems-with-cmidrule-and-cline

Comment: I can only reproduce the issue only with `\usepackage[czech]{babel}` (or `slovak`). As such, this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

i cant confirm your problem. after completion of your code fragment i obtain

[image]

mwe (minimal working example):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l| c|c| c|c|}                                                                                        \hline
    Typ algoritmu                   & Kryptosystém      & Level bezpe\v cnosti (bit)
                                                               &      &      &          \\
                                    &                   & 80   & 128  & 192  & 256      \\
    Faktorizácia celých \v císel    & RSA               & 1024 & 3072 & 7680 & 15360    \\
    Diskrétny logaritmus            & DH, DSA, Elgamal  & 1024 & 3072 & 7680 & 15360    \\
\cline{1-2}
    Eliptické krivky                & ECDH, ECDSA       & 160  & 256  & 384  & 512      \\
    Symetrický                      & AES, 3DES         & 80   & 128  & 192  & 256      \\                                                                                       \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

please observe:

- to your document i add `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` that your code fragment become complete small document, which is possible to test (as i ask you to do)
- add missed ampersands in the first row

as you can test, your table code doesn't cause your problem. to see, what is going on at you, you should provide mwe, which show your problem.

**addendum:**

i suspect that `Level bezpe\v cnosti (bit)` should be in `\multicoumn{4}{c}{...}` cell. further improvements should be use of `utf8` input encoding, use of `booktabs` package for horizontal lines, omit vertical lines and use `S` column type from `siunitx` package. all this measure gives (tomy opinion) more open and professional look of table:

[image]

mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % added
\usepackage{booktabs}       % added
\usepackage{siunitx}        % added

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll 
           *{4}{S[table-format=5.0,   % chBGED FROM "cccc"
                  group-four-digits]} 
                }                                                                                        \toprule
    Typ algoritmu                   & Kryptosystém      
                                                     & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Level bezpečnosti (bit)}\\  % changed
\midrule
                              &                  & 80   & 128  & 192  & 256      \\
    Faktorizácia celých čísel & RSA              & 1024 & 3072 & 7680 & 15360    \\
    Diskrétny logaritmus      & DH, DSA, Elgamal & 1024 & 3072 & 7680 & 15360    \\
\midrule{1-2}
    Eliptické krivky          & ECDH, ECDSA      & 160  & 256  & 384  & 512      \\
    Symetrický                & AES, 3DES        & 80   & 128  & 192  & 256      \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```