# Table - longer numbers

Tags: tables

How to center please the last cell ?

```
\multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{$M_1$} \\[0.33ex]
```

How to write longer number to table? Multicolumns are not connected to the below part? Thank you

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}  % choose suitable text block parameters
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm} 
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{icomma,dcolumn,booktabs} 

\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e} % new
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{,}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L d{3.2} d{1.2} d{2.3} d{2.3} *{4}{d{3.2}} @{}}
\toprule
Zdroj & 
\mc{$P$} & 
\mc{$T_0$}  & 
\mc{$e$} &
\mc{$\omega$} & 
\mc{$i$} & 
\mc{$a$} & 
\mc{$a$} &

\multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{$M_1$} \\[0.33ex]
  & \mc{(dny)}
  & \mc{(RJD)}
  & \mc{} 
  & \mc{($ {\rm ^\circ}$)} 
  & \mc{($ {\rm ^\circ}$)}
  & \mc{($ {\rm R_{\odot}}$)} 
  & \mc{($ {\rm M_{\odot}}$)} 
  & \mc{($ {\rm M_{\odot}}$)}   
  \\
\midrule

1 & 5,732436(15) & 54002,780(46) & 12.345 & 123.45 & 123.45 & 123.45 & 123.45 &\\

\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{8}{@{}l}{\footnotesize\textit{Pozn:} $^a$ Směrodatná chyba odhadu metodou Monte Carlo.}
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Maximálně věrohodné odhady v~modelu M.}\label{tab03:Nejaka}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**
Where do I please make mistake when I want to delete two columns?

I have this code?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}  % choose suitable text block parameters
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm} 
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx} 

\newcommand{\Mo}{\mathrm{M}_{\odot}}
\newcommand{\Ro}{\mathrm{R}_{\odot}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\footnotesize

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=1.6(2)]
  S[table-format=5.3(2)]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  *{5}{S[table-format=3.2]}
  @{}
}
\toprule
Zdroj & 
{$P$} & 
{$T_0$}  & 
{$e$} &
{$\omega$} & 
{$i$} & 
{$a$} & 
{$a$} &
{$M_1$} \\[0.33ex]
  & {(dny)}
  & {(RJD)}
  & {} 
  & {(${}^\circ$)} 
  & {(${}^\circ$)} 
  & {($\Ro$)}
  & {($\Mo$)}
  & {($\Mo$)}   
  \\
\midrule

1 & 5,732436(15) & 54002,780(46) & 12.345 & 123.45 & 123.45 & 123.45 & 123.45 &\\

\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{9}{@{}l}{\textit{Pozn:} $^a$ Směrodatná chyba odhadu metodou Monte Carlo.}
\end{tabular*}

\caption{Maximálně věrohodné odhady v~modelu M.}\label{tab03:Nejaka}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I eddited in bad way:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english,czech]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm} 
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{icomma,dcolumn,booktabs} 

\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e} 
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{,}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L cc c c *{2}{c} @{}}
\toprule
Zdroj & $P$ & $T_0$ & \mc{$e$} & \mc{$\omega$} & \mc{$i$} & \mc{$a$} & \mc{$a$} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{$M_1$} \\[0.33ex]
& (dny) & (RJD) & & \mc{($^\circ$)}  &  \mc{($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$)} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$)} \\
\midrule
1 & 5,732436(15) & 54002,780(46) & 0,0910(37) & 12.345 & 123.45 & 123.45 \\

\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{\footnotesize\textit{Pozn:} $^a$ Směrodatná chyba odhadu metodou Monte Carlo.}
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Maximálně věrohodné odhady v~modelu M.}\label{tab03:Nejaka}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In `\multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{$M_1$}` ... what does `@{}` do?

Comment: Can you explain what the numbers in `d{2.3}` are meaning? I don't have the documentation at hand.

Comment: @Johannes_B - the `@{}` particle is there to suppress whitespace padding which would otherwise be inserted by LaTeX. The numerals before and after the decimal marker in `d{2.3}` signify the number of digits to be set aside by LaTeX.

Comment: @Mico I know. I asked Elisabeth to explain it to me.

Comment: @Johannes_B - If she knew what these things mean, she would be able to solve her own quesions right away....

Comment: @Mico Indeed. I want to encourage her to think about the problem she has. Thinking is crucial to learn. Imho

Comment: How to write please a column with no specific number of decimal places to get decimal point under themseves? Thnak you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- The particle `$M_1$` is actually placed correctly at the moment. (Recall that whitespace padding at both edges of the table is suppressed, courtesy of the `@{}` particles.) It's the `\mc{($ {\rm M_{\odot}}$)}` item that is not placed correctly. Just as you did for the case of

  ```
  \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{$M_1$}
  ```

  you have to write

  ```
  \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{($(\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$)}
  ```

  in order to get the placement just right.

  Note that `{\rm ...}` is badly deprecated in LaTeX documents. Don't use is. Intead, write `\mathrm{...}`.
- The `d` column type is meant to be employed if the numbers in the column need to be aligned on their decimal markers. If that's not the case, you shouldn't even be using the `d` column type. You haven't provided much information about the actual types of numbers that may occur in columns 2 and 3. Absent more specific information, all I can assume is that simple centering (via the `c` column type) is fine for these two columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm} 
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{icomma,dcolumn,booktabs} 

\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e} 
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{,}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
%\footnotesize % Don't use footnotesize unless you want to make the material difficult to read
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L cc d{2.3} d{2.3} *{4}{d{3.2}} @{}}
\toprule
Zdroj & $P$ & $T_0$ & \mc{$e$} &
\mc{$\omega$} & \mc{$i$} & \mc{$a$} & \mc{$a$} &
\multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{$M_1$} \\[0.33ex]
& (dny) & (RJD) & & \mc{($^\circ$)} & \mc{($^\circ$)}
& \mc{($\mathrm{R}_{\odot}$)} & \mc{($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$)} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$)} \\
\midrule
Bla bla bla bla bla bla 
& 5,732436(15) & 54002,780(46) 
& 12.345 & 12.345 & 123.45 & 123.45 & 123.45 & 123.45\\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{8}{@{}l}{\footnotesize\textit{Pozn:} $^a$ Směrodatná chyba odhadu metodou Monte Carlo.}
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Maximálně věrohodné odhady v~modelu M.}\label{tab03:Nejaka}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much
It works when I have `\usepackage[czech,english]{babel}` but not when I have `\usepackage[czech]{babel}`
and when I have the first variant it works, but I have names of \tableofcontents, \listoffigures in final .pdf file in english. How it change please?

Comment: @Elisabeth - Did you try `\usepackage[english,czech]{babel}`?

Comment: How can I plese delete two of columns? I eddited the question.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `siunitx`, which covers much more than `dcolumn` does.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}  % choose suitable text block parameters
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm} 
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx} 

\newcommand{\Mo}{\mathrm{M}_{\odot}}
\newcommand{\Ro}{\mathrm{R}_{\odot}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\footnotesize

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=1.6(2)]
  S[table-format=5.3(2)]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  *{5}{S[table-format=3.2]}
  @{}
}
\toprule
Zdroj & 
{$P$} & 
{$T_0$}  & 
{$e$} &
{$\omega$} & 
{$i$} & 
{$a$} & 
{$a$} &
{$M_1$} \\[0.33ex]
  & {(dny)}
  & {(RJD)}
  & {} 
  & {(${}^\circ$)} 
  & {(${}^\circ$)} 
  & {($\Ro$)}
  & {($\Mo$)}
  & {($\Mo$)}   
  \\
\midrule

1 & 5,732436(15) & 54002,780(46) & 12.345 & 123.45 & 123.45 & 123.45 & 123.45 &\\

\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{9}{@{}l}{\textit{Pozn:} $^a$ Směrodatná chyba odhadu metodou Monte Carlo.}
\end{tabular*}

\caption{Maximálně věrohodné odhady v~modelu M.}\label{tab03:Nejaka}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\rm` has been deprecated for more than 20 years. The correct syntax is `\mathrm{M}_{\odot}`, but I added a couple of new commands for ease of input.

See also [Slovak (and Czech) babel gives problems with cmidrule and cline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111999/4427) for problems with `\cmidrule`.

[image]

Comment: I have a problem with siunitx package  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMsXQ.png

Comment: @Elisabeth You have to update your TeX system.