# Table - consequential lines

Tags: tables

How to change this table to the line left continue (1. column can be left align) and how to make a space in cell with CFF? Is it possible to center text in cells vertically? Thank you

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\setlength\textwidth{145mm}
\setlength\textheight{247mm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\evensidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\topmargin{0mm}
\setlength\headsep{0mm}
\setlength\headheight{0mm}
\let\openright=\clearpage
\usepackage[a-2u]{pdfx}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\NewDocumentCommand{\anote}{}{\makebox[0pt][l]{$^*$}}

\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}


\usepackage{amsfonts}       

\usepackage{makecell,threeparttable}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{0.25ex}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{,}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\stack[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack{#1}}}
\newcommand{\angstrom}{\mbox{\normalfont\AA}}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{%
   \bgroup%
   \setlength\extrarowheight{0pt}%
   \smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}%
   \egroup}
%%% code block to handle the OP's follow-up question -- see
%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112002/5001 for the source
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
% Change the `-` delimiter to an active character
\xpatchparametertext\@cline{-}{\cA-}{}{}
\makeatother
\hfuzz=99pt

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
    \scriptsize
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default: 6pt
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{5}{C|}>{\hsize=1.6\hsize}C| >{\hsize=0.4\hsize}C| *{3}{C|}}
    \hline
    \multirowcell{4}{Veličina} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{[1]} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{[2]} & [3] & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{[4]} \\
    \cline{2-10}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirowcell{1.5}{PHOEBE fotometrie a RV}}
     & \multirow{3}{=}{\centering POWR analýza} & %
    \multirow{3}{=}{\centering Řešení světelných křivek a RV} &
    \multirowcell{3}{CFF }& \multirow{3}{=}{\centering Model malá hmotnost} & \multirow{3}{=}{\centering Model střední hmotnost} & \multirow{3}{=}{\centering Model velká hmotnost} \\[1ex]
    \cline{2-4}
    & \multirowcell{1.5}{Řešení I} & \multirowcell{1.5}{Řešení II} &\multirowcell{1.5}{Řešení III} & & & & & &\\ [1.5ex]
    \hline
        \end{tabularx}\vskip 0.3ex
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C|*{4}{C} >{\hsize=1.3\hsize}C >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}C *{3}{C}}
     \hline
     $P$ (dny) & & & & & & & & \\
     $T_0$ (RJD) & & & & & & & & \\
     $e$  ( ) & & & & & & & & \\
     $\omega$ (\si{\degree}) & & & & & & & & \\
     $K_1$ (\si{\kilo\meter\per\second}) & & & & & & & & \\
     $K_2$ (\si{\kilo\meter\per\second}) & & & & & & & & \\
     $a$ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$) & & & & & & & & \\
     $i$  (\si{\degree}) & & & & & & & \\
     $T_1$ (\si{\kelvin}) & & & & & & & \\
     $T_2$ (\si{\kelvin}) & & & & & & & \\
     $\Omega_1$ (\si{\degree}) & & & & & & & \\
     $\Omega_2$ (\si{\degree}) & & & & & & & \\
     $q = \dfrac{M_2}{M_1}$ & & & & & & & \\
     $M_1$ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$) & & & & & & & \\
     $M_2$  ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$) & & & & & & & \\
     $R_1$ ($\mathrm{R}_{\odot}$) & & & & & & & \\
     $R_2$ ($\mathrm{R}_{\odot}$) & & & & & & & \\
     $V_{\gamma}$ (\si{\kilo\meter\per\second}) & & & & & & & \\

     \end{tabularx}
 \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
    [1] \\
    [2] \\
    [3] \\
    [4] \\
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}   
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\setlength\textwidth{145mm}
\setlength\textheight{247mm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\evensidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\topmargin{0mm}
\setlength\headsep{0mm}
\setlength\headheight{0mm}
\let\openright=\clearpage
\usepackage[a-2u]{pdfx}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, graphicx,threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\NewDocumentCommand{\anote}{}{\makebox[0pt][l]{$^*$}}

\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}


\usepackage{amsfonts}       % matematické fonty
\usepackage{amsthm}         % sazba vět, definic apod.
\usepackage{bbding}         % balíček s nejrůznějšími symboly
                % (čtverečky, hvězdičky, tužtičky, nůžtičky, ...)
\usepackage{bm}             % tučné symboly (příkaz \bm)
\usepackage{fancyvrb}       % vylepšené prostředí pro strojové písmo
\usepackage{indentfirst}    % zavede odsazení 1. odstavce kapitoly
\usepackage{natbib}         % zajištuje možnost odkazovat na literaturu
                % stylem AUTOR (ROK), resp. AUTOR [ČÍSLO]
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % zajistí přidání seznamu literatury,
\usepackage{icomma}         
\usepackage{booktabs}       % lepší vodorovné linky v tabulkách
\usepackage{paralist}       % lepší enumerate a itemize
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{0.25ex}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{,}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\stack[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack{#1}}}
\newcommand{\angstrom}{\mbox{\normalfont\AA}}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{%
   \bgroup%
   \setlength\extrarowheight{0pt}%
   \smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}%
   \egroup}
%%% code block to handle the OP's follow-up question -- see
%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112002/5001 for the source
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
% Change the `-` delimiter to an active character
\xpatchparametertext\@cline{-}{\cA-}{}{}
\makeatother
\hfuzz=99pt
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
    \scriptsize
    \renewcommand{\cellset}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.75}\scriptsize}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default: 6pt
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C|*{2}{C} >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}C >{\hsize=1.3\hsize}Cc*{3}{C}}
    \Xhline{0.8pt}\noalign{\vskip 0.4ex}\Xhline{0.8pt}%
    \multirowcell{4}{Veličina} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{[1]} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{[2]} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{[3]} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{[4]} \\[0.4ex]
    \cline{2-9}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirowcell{1.5}{PHOEBE fotometrie a RV}}
     &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{3}{POWR\\ analýza}} & %
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{3}{Řešení\\ světelných\\ křivek a RV}} &
   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \multirowcell{3}{CFF }}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \multirowcell{3}{Model\\malá\\ hmotnost}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{3}{Model\\ střední\\ hmotnost}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{3}{Model\\ velká\\ hmotnost}} \\[1ex]
    \cline{2-3}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{1.5}{Řešení II}} & \multicolumn{1}  `{c|}{\multirowcell{1.5}{Řešení III}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\ [1.5ex]`
    \Xhline{0.8pt}%
     $P$ (dny) & & & & & & & \\
     $T_0$ (RJD) & & & & & & && \\
     $e$ ( ) & & & & & & & \\
     $\omega$ (\si{\degree}) & & & & & & & \\
     $K_1$ (\si{\kilo\meter\per\second}) & & & & & & & \\
     $K_2$ (\si{\kilo\meter\per\second}) & & & & & & & \\
     $a$ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$) & & & & & & & \\
     $i$ (\si{\degree}) & & & & & & & \\
     $T_1$ (\si{\kelvin}) & & & & & & & \\
     $T_2$ (\si{\kelvin}) & & & & & & & \\
     $\Omega_1$ (\si{\degree}) & & & & & & & \\
     $\Omega_2$ (\si{\degree}) & & & & & & & \\
     $q = \dfrac{M_2}{M_1}$ & & & & & & & \\
     $M_1$ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$) & & & & & & & \\
     $M_2$ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$) & & & & & & & \\
     $R_1$ ($\mathrm{R}_{\odot}$) & & & & & & & \\
     $R_2$ ($\mathrm{R}_{\odot}$) & & & & & & & \\
     $V_{\gamma }$ (\si{\kilo\meter\per\second}) & & & & & & & \\    
     \end{tabularx}
    \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
    \item[]\\{[1]} \\
    {[2]} \\
    {[3]} \\
    {[4]} \\
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The easy solution to this problem: don't use vertical lines. Also see http://betterposters.blogspot.com/2012/08/the-data-prison.html

Comment: Off-topic: instead of manually messing with your page geometry, you might want to look into the `geometry` package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this more like what you want? I slightly modified the values for `\hsize`, used a single `tabularx` and adapted your page dimensions to `geometry`(not sure it's exactly what you had in mind, though. Please check):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[textwidth=145mm, textheight=247mm, nohead, showframe]{geometry}
\let\openright=\clearpage
%\usepackage[a-2u]{pdfx}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\NewDocumentCommand{\anote}{}{\makebox[0pt][l]{$^*$}}

\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}


\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{makecell,threeparttable}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
%\setlength\heavyrulewidth{0.25ex}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{,}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\stack[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack{#1}}}
\newcommand{\angstrom}{\mbox{\normalfont\AA}}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{%
   \bgroup%
   \setlength\extrarowheight{0pt}%
   \smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}%
   \egroup}
%%% code block to handle the OP's follow-up question -- see
%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112002/5001 for the source
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
% Change the `-` delimiter to an active character
\xpatchparametertext\@cline{-}{\cA-}{}{}
\makeatother
\hfuzz=99pt

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
    \scriptsize
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default: 6pt
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{5}{C|}>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}C| >{\hsize=0.5\hsize}C| *{3}{C|}}
    \hline
    \multirowcell{4}{Veličina} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{[1]} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{[2]} & [3] & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{[4]} \\
    \cline{2-10}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirowcell{1.5}{PHOEBE fotometrie a RV}}
     & \multirow{3}{=}{\centering POWR analýza} & %
    \multirow{3}{=}{\centering Řešení světelných křivek a RV} &
    \multirowcell{3}{CFF }& \multirow{3}{=}{\centering Model malá hmotnost} & \multirow{3}{=}{\centering Model střední hmotnost} & \multirow{3}{=}{\centering Model velká hmotnost} \\[1ex]
    \cline{2-4}
    & \multirowcell{1.5}{Řešení I} & \multirowcell{1.5}{Řešení II} &\multirowcell{1.5}{Řešení III} & & & & & &\\ [1.5ex]
    \hline\noalign{\vskip 0.5ex}
     \hline
     $P$ (dny) & & & & & & & & \\
     $T_0$ (RJD) & & & & & & & & \\
     $e$ ( ) & & & & & & & & \\
     $\omega$ (\si{\degree}) & & & & & & & & \\
     $K_1$ (\si{\kilo\meter\per\second}) & & & & & & & & \\
     $K_2$ (\si{\kilo\meter\per\second}) & & & & & & & & \\
     $a$ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$) & & & & & & & & \\
     $i$ (\si{\degree}) & & & & & & & \\
     $T_1$ (\si{\kelvin}) & & & & & & & \\
     $T_2$ (\si{\kelvin}) & & & & & & & \\
     $\Omega_1$ (\si{\degree}) & & & & & & & \\
     $\Omega_2$ (\si{\degree}) & & & & & & & \\
     $q = \dfrac{M_2}{M_1}$ & & & & & & & \\
     $M_1$ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$) & & & & & & & \\
     $M_2$ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$) & & & & & & & \\
     $R_1$ ($\mathrm{R}_{\odot}$) & & & & & & & \\
     $R_2$ ($\mathrm{R}_{\odot}$) & & & & & & & \\
     $V_{\gamma}$ (\si{\kilo\meter\per\second}) & & & & & & & \\

     \end{tabularx}
 \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
   \item[]\\{[1]} \\
 {[2]} \\
    {[3]} \\
  {[4]} \\
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want vertical lines in the second part of the table, here is a code that realises it:

```
\begin{table}[ht!]
    \scriptsize
\renewcommand{\cellset}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.75}\scriptsize}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default: 6pt
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C|*{3}{C} >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}C >{\hsize=1.3\hsize}Cc*{3}{C}}
    \hline
    \multirowcell{4}{Veličina} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{[1]} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{[2]} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{[3]} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{[4]} \\
    \cline{2-10}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirowcell{1.5}{PHOEBE fotometrie a RV}}
     &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{3}{POWR\\ analýza}} & %
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{3}{Řešení\\ světelných\\ křivek a RV}} &
   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \multirowcell{3}{CFF }}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \multirowcell{3}{Model\\malá\\ hmotnost}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{3}{Model\\ střední\\ hmotnost}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{3}{Model\\ velká\\ hmotnost}} \\[1ex]
    \cline{2-4}
    &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \multirowcell{1.5}{Řešení I}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{1.5}{Řešení II}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{1.5}{Řešení III}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\ [1.5ex]
    \hline\noalign{\vskip 0.5ex}
     \hline
     $P$ (dny) & & & & & & & & \\
     $T₀$ (RJD) & & & & & & & & \\
     $e$ ( ) & & & & & & & & \\
     $\omega$ (\si{\degree}) & & & & & & & & \\
     $K₁$ (\si{\kilo\meter\per\second}) & & & & & & & & \\
     $K₂$ (\si{\kilo\meter\per\second}) & & & & & & & & \\
     $a$ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$) & & & & & & & & \\
     $i$ (\si{\degree}) & & & & & & & \\
     $T₁$ (\si{\kelvin}) & & & & & & & \\
     $T₂$ (\si{\kelvin}) & & & & & & & \\
     $\Omega₁$ (\si{\degree}) & & & & & & & \\
     $\Omega₂$ (\si{\degree}) & & & & & & & \\
     $q = \dfrac{M₂}{M₁}$ & & & & & & & \\
     $M₁$ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$) & & & & & & & \\
     $M₂$ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$) & & & & & & & \\
     $R₁$ ($\mathrm{R}_{\odot}$) & & & & & & & \\
     $R₂$ ($\mathrm{R}_{\odot}$) & & & & & & & \\
     $V_{γ}$ (\si{\kilo\meter\per\second}) & & & & & & & \\

     \end{tabularx}
 \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
   \item[]\\{[1]} \\
 {[2]} \\
    {[3]} \\
  {[4]} \\
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
```

[image]

*Edit*: Here is a code for your last requirement:

```
    \begin{table}[ht!]
    \scriptsize
    \renewcommand{\cellset}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.75}\scriptsize}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default: 6pt
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C|*{2}{C} >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}C >{\hsize=1.3\hsize}Cc*{3}{C}}
    \Xhline{0.8pt}\noalign{\vskip 0.4ex}\Xhline{0.8pt}%
    \multirowcell{4}{Veličina} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{[1]} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{[2]} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{[3]} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{[4]} \\[0.4ex]
    \cline{2-9}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirowcell{1.5}{PHOEBE fotometrie a RV}}
     &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{3}{POWR\\ analýza}} & %
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{3}{Řešení\\ světelných\\ křivek a RV}} &
   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \multirowcell{3}{CFF }}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \multirowcell{3}{Model\\malá\\ hmotnost}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{3}{Model\\ střední\\ hmotnost}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{3}{Model\\ velká\\ hmotnost}} \\[1ex]
    \cline{2-3}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{1.5}{Řešení II}} & \multicolumn{1}  `{c|}{\multirowcell{1.5}{Řešení III}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\ [1.5ex]`
    \Xhline{0.8pt}%
     $P$ (dny) & & & & & & & \\
     $T_0$ (RJD) & & & & & & && \\
     $e$ ( ) & & & & & & & \\
     $\omega$ (\si{\degree}) & & & & & & & \\
     $K_1$ (\si{\kilo\meter\per\second}) & & & & & & & \\
     $K_2$ (\si{\kilo\meter\per\second}) & & & & & & & \\
     $a$ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$) & & & & & & & \\
     $i$ (\si{\degree}) & & & & & & & \\
     $T_1$ (\si{\kelvin}) & & & & & & & \\
     $T_2$ (\si{\kelvin}) & & & & & & & \\
     $\Omega_1$ (\si{\degree}) & & & & & & & \\
     $\Omega_2$ (\si{\degree}) & & & & & & & \\
     $q = \dfrac{M_2}{M_1}$ & & & & & & & \\
     $M_1$ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$) & & & & & & & \\
     $M_2$ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$) & & & & & & & \\
     $R_1$ ($\mathrm{R}_{\odot}$) & & & & & & & \\
     $R_2$ ($\mathrm{R}_{\odot}$) & & & & & & & \\
     $V_{\gamma }$ (\si{\kilo\meter\per\second}) & & & & & & & \\    
     \end{tabularx}
    \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
    \item[]\\{[1]} \\
    {[2]} \\
    {[3]} \\
    {[4]} \\
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much and where to set no vertical lines in body of table?

Comment: What you ask is a bit unclear. Do you mean how to remove vertical lines in specific cells, when a vertical line has been declared in the table preamble?

Comment: I ment this lines   [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqIQx.png. When I tried to delete it I spoiled the preamble.

Comment: @Elisabeth: I've added another code to do what you want (hopefully…)

Comment: Thank you very much and in what line did you do that?

Comment: Well, it's more complex than doing it in just a single line: I removed the vertical  lines from the table preamble (except the 1st, 2nd and last), and replaced them in the first part of the table – the table head, so to say – with a series of `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{...}` where needed.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMrQT.png Please, can I ask you for one more table? Can the line in yellow be bold like lines at top and bottom and the cell deleted as well as denoted lines? I added the actual code in EDIT in my question. Thank you very much

Comment: @Elisabeth: Please my last edit to see if it's OK for you.

Comment: Thank you very very much. And please, what is a mistake in the head of document? It writes a mistake about defining c column. Whole code is in edit

Comment: There's no mistake in the head of the document, but your table has two unwanted backticks; line 80, you have  `\multicolumn{1} `{c|}{\multirowcell{1.5}{Řešení III}}` instead of \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{1.5}{Řešení III}} and, a little further, you have  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\ [1.5ex]` instead of `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\ [1.5ex]`.

Comment: You're welcome! B.t.w. the `usenames` option of `xcolor` is unnecessary: it's been the default for quite some years.