# longtable and adjustbox/textwidth

Tags: longtable, adjustbox, textwidth

Can this table be put on the width of the text ? I have tried many things but they didn't work.

```
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}[c]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cccccccccc@{}}
\centering
\caption{Zoznam, zapojenie a parametre vedení 110 kV} \label{tab:long1} \\
% First head

\hline
\multicolumn{10}{c}{Vedenia} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Názov} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Uzol 1} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Uzol 2} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$R_1 {[}\Omega{]}$}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$X_1 {[}\Omega{]}$}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$B_1 {[}\mu S{]}$}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$R_0 {[}\Omega{]}$}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$X_0 {[}\Omega{]}$}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$B0 {[}\mu S{]}$}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$I_{dov} {[}A{]}$}
\\ \hline
\endfirsthead
% Standard head
\multicolumn{10}{c}
{{\tablename\ \thetable{} \textit{(Pokračovanie)}}} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Názov} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Uzol 1} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Uzol 2} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$R_1 {[}\Omega{]}$}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$X_1 {[}\Omega{]}$}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$B_1 {[}\mu S{]}$}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$R_0 {[}\Omega{]}$}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$X_0 {[}\Omega{]}$}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$B_0 \mu S{]}$}& 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$I_{dov} {[}A{]}$}
\\ \hline
\endhead
% Footnote 
\hline\multicolumn{10}{r}{{\textit{Pokračovanie na ďalšej strane...}}} \\ 
\endfoot
% Last footnote
\hline
\endlastfoot

%%%Table%%%

\end{longtable}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: why do you have `\multicolumn{1}{c}` ? You can remove them all, your columns are already centred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using one of the standard document classes (article, report, or book) or a document class that's built on a standard document class, the following code should work just fine. A main change, relative to the code fragment you posted, is moving the units to a separate header row; this makes each column just that much less wide.

The following code also contains a fix for an incompatibility between slovak/babel and some of the macros of the `booktabs` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% fix incompatibility between babel/slovak and booktabs macros:
\begingroup % see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112001/5001
    \makeatletter
    \catcode`\-=\active
    \AtBeginDocument{
    \def\@@@cmidrule[#1-#2]#3#4{\global\@cmidla#1\relax
        \global\advance\@cmidla\m@ne
        \ifnum\@cmidla>0\global\let\@gtempa\@cmidrulea\else
        \global\let\@gtempa\@cmidruleb\fi
        \global\@cmidlb#2\relax
        \global\advance\@cmidlb-\@cmidla
        \global\@thisrulewidth=#3
        \@setrulekerning{#4}
        \ifnum\@lastruleclass=\z@\vskip \aboverulesep\fi
        \ifnum0=`{\fi}\@gtempa
        \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\futurenonspacelet\@tempa\@xcmidrule}
    }
\endgroup

\begin{document}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}[c]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{9}{c} @{}}
%%\centering % <-- not needed

% First head
\caption{Zoznam, zapojenie a parametre vedení \qty{110}{\kilo\volt}} \label{tab:long1} \\
\toprule
Názov & \multicolumn{9}{c@{}}{Vedenia} \\
\cmidrule{2-10}
& Uzol 1 & Uzol 2 & $R_1$ & $X_1$ & $B_1$ & $R_0$ & $X_0$ & $B_0$ & $I_{\mathrm{dov}}$\\
& & & [\unit{\ohm}] & [\unit{\ohm}] & [\unit{\micro\second}] 
    & [\unit{\ohm}] & [\unit{\ohm}] & [\unit{\micro\second}] 
    & [\unit{\ampere}]\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead


%% Standard head
\multicolumn{10}{@{}l}{\tablename\ \thetable\ \textit{(Pokračovanie)}} \\
\toprule
Názov & \multicolumn{9}{c@{}}{Vedenia} \\
\cmidrule{2-10}
& Uzol 1 & Uzol 2 & $R_1$ & $X_1$ & $B_1$ & $R_0$ & $X_0$ & $B_0$ & $I_{\mathrm{dov}}$\\
& & & [\unit{\ohm}] & [\unit{\ohm}] & [\unit{\micro\second}] 
    & [\unit{\ohm}] & [\unit{\ohm}] & [\unit{\micro\second}] 
    & [\unit{\ampere}]\\
\midrule
\endhead

% Footer 
\midrule
\multicolumn{10}{r@{}}{\footnotesize\emph{Pokračovanie na ďalšej strane\dots}} \\ 
\endfoot

% Last footer
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

%%%Table%%%
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With use of the `tabularray` package the table code is simple and short:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
    \DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{normal}{(Pokračovanie)}
    \SetTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{normal}
    \DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}{Pokračovanie na ďalšej strane \dots}
    \SetTblrStyle{contfoot-text}{font=\small\sffamily\itshape, gray5}
    \SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Zoznam, zapojenie a parametre vedení \qty{110}{\kilo\volt}},
  label = {tab:long1}
                ]{%colsep = 3pt,
                 colspec = {@{} l *{9}{X[c]} @{}},
                  row{1} = {mode=text},
                 rowhead = 1
                 }
    \toprule   
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    Názov   
    &   \SetCell[c=9]{c}    Vedenia
            &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    \midrule
& Uzol 1 & Uzol 2 
            & $R_1$ [\unit{\ohm}]
                & $X_1$ [\unit{\ohm}]
                    & $B_1$ [\unit{\micro\second}]
                        & $R_0$ [\unit{\ohm}]
                            & $X_0$ [\unit{\ohm}] 
                                & $B_0$ [\unit{\micro\second}]
                                    & $I_{\mathrm{dov}}$ [\unit{\ampere}]
                                        \\
    \midrule
% table body 
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\

\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]